# Save changes while migrating Suitecrm

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Is it Possible to migrate `SuiteCRM` from one server to other without losing the changes in /custom and without exporting the existing `Database` i.e. I want to migrate `SuiteCRM` but the condition is that `SuiteCRM` should not lose any modifications done through studio or code and when installed in other server, it should contain all the changes made previously without exporting `Database`.
I think i have to make changes in install.php file of Suite.

Any help will be appreciated.